# Including jars in classpath on commandline (javac or apt)

Tags: java, jar

trying to run this program.  I think that to setup all of the web service stuff I need to run apt.  (Although using javac I am having the same issue).  I think what I am getting is compile errors.  (Shown at bottom).

I think what I need to do is include this jar in my class path: jsr181-api.jar [(source)](http://community.jboss.org/message/338674#338674).  Is there a simple temporary way to do this (on solaris)?  I don't want to add it to my bash_rc file (it is there forever).  I also know that there is some way to do it using a manifest text file but that seemed complicated so I didn't look into it yet.  Can I just do something like:

```
javac HelloImp <listOfJars>
```

or

```
ant HelloImp <listOfJars>
```

**Code:**

```
package server;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class HelloImpl {

  /**
   * @param name
   * @return Say hello to the person.
   */
   public String sayHello(String name) {
     return "Hello, " + name + "!";
   }
}
```

**Compile errors:**

```
HelloImpl.java:3: package javax.jws does not exist
import javax.jws.WebService;
                 ^
HelloImpl.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol: class WebService
@WebService
 ^
2 errors
```

**Update:**  Cool that is wrapped up but it is still not quite working.  I have created a  [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096437/apt-warning-no-annotation-processor-found)  to keep things nice and organized:

Comment: As a side note, some jars are only needed during compilation (ie `javac`) but not at runtime (ie `java`). For example, the `lombok` jar.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Try the following:

```
java -cp jar1:jar2:jar3:dir1:. HelloWorld
```

In Windows use ;

```
java -cp jar1;jar2;jar3;dir1;. HelloWorld
```

The default classpath (unless there is a CLASSPATH environment variable) is the current directory so if you redefine it, make sure you're adding the current directory (.) to the classpath as I have done.

Comment: https://github.com/SpotterRF/json-examples/tree/master/java/jackson has a good example in the Makefile

Comment: @CoolAJ86 The link seems to have gone dead

Comment: The best way I found is to use `java -cp *:. HelloWorld`. That way all jars in my classpath are always included.

Answer (score 36):

In windows:

```
java -cp C:/.../jardir1/*;C:/.../jardir2/* class_with_main_method
```

make sure that the class with the main function is in one of the included jars

Answer (score 32):

Note for Windows users, the jars should be separated by `;` and not `:`.

for example:
`javac -cp external_libs\lib1.jar;other\lib2.jar;`

Comment: Also, in PowerShell, the classpath needs to be quoted, e.g. -cp ".;MyJar.jar"

Answer (score 17):

Use the `-cp` or `-classpath` switch.

```
$ java -help  
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]  
           (to execute a class)  
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]  
           (to execute a jar file)  

where options include:  
...  
    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>  
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>  
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,  
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
```

(Note that the separator used to separate entries on the classpath differs between OSes, on my Windows machine it is `;`, in *nix it is usually `:`.)

Answer (score 2):

> javac HelloWorld.java -classpath ./javax.jar , assuming javax is in current folder, and compile target is "HelloWorld.java", and you can compile without a main method