# Install org.apache.commons.io?

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

I have a program that is trying to use the org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils static method

```
readFileToString()
```

I have downloaded the commons.io package from the Apache website but I don't know how to get my program to find the package. I am not currently using an IDE, but am using Notepad ++ and using a simple batch file to compile, and another batch file to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set a classpath in both

1. compile process (javac) and
2. runtime (java)

see a similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt).