# Cannot recognise "import org.junit.Assert" in a java file

Tags: java

I have this problem that I cannot understand why it doesn't exist.

Basically, when I compile the following command:

```
C:\Users\Bill\My Documents\Antbook\ch04> javac -d build\test test\org\example\antbook\junit\SimpleTest.java
```

It gives me an error saying: "java:4 error: Package org.junit does not exist" and same with line 5. Plus, on line 9, it cannot find the "@Test".

Heres, the code:

```
package org.example.antbook.junit; 

//import JUnit4 classes:
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest
{
    @Test    
    public void testSomething() 
    {
        assertTrue("MULTIPLICATION???", 4 == (2 * 2));
    }
}
```

Can anyone give any suggestions? Am I meant to copy the jar files containing the Junit classes in to a directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to put it in a dedicated folder for your libraries (ie. jar files) and include that directory in the classpath when you execute `javac` on the command line. In this case, if you are only using one jar file `junit-4.11.jar`, then this will work.

```
C:\Users\Bill\My Documents\Antbook\ch04> javac -cp yourLibDir\junit-4.11.jar -d build\test test\org\example\antbook\junit\SimpleTest.java
```

If you have more jar files, use a `*` to include through all the jar files in a dir on the classpath:

```
 javac -cp yourLibDir\*
```

Comment: Hey bizmark, It works! Your example worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much! I blame my teacher for making these mistakes.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't be too hard on the prof, it's the learning that counts, not the teaching :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add junit-latestversion.jar under your lib folder and include it in your class path

Here is the way to add classpath from command line

java -cp jar1:jar2:jar3:dir1:. HelloWorld

Here is thje link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering where do you put the jar file in the lib folder? I am currently using NotePad++ and I don't think I am allowed to use eclipse.