# class not found error in java when compiling a project with libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I have created a project in eclipse and added `jdbc jar` library successfully.When I run the program in eclipse I see no error but When I type:

```
 javac *.java
```

in console no problem occur but later when I type

```
java Runner
```

I get `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`
and more errors related to this."`Runner`" is the class which has the main method. But in eclipse eveyrthing was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This means `com.mysql.jdbc.Drive` is not on your classpath at runtime when you run your program outside of Eclipse. Add it to your classpath.

Try `java -classpath` or `java -cp`.

Try also `java -help` for help and additional details.

See also: http://reins.altervista.org/java/A_Collection_of_JVM_Options_MP.html

Answer (score 0):

You need the jar file at run time as well.

Use `java -cp pathToYourJar Runner`

Comment: I have put my jar file to the lib directory of the directory where  other class files exist but still getting the same error .my command is: java -cp /home/project/443/lib:. Runner

Comment: What is your jar name?

Answer (score 0):

Because eclipse already has a classpath, when running from command line you need to specify it also.

Answer (score 0):

As the others say, you need to pass to javac command the classpath, the way to do it is explained in the following question

[Including jars in classpath on commandline (javac or apt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt)