# how to add json library to fedora14

Tags: java, json

I am in need of the json package,
these are the imports i need to resolve:

```
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
//import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
class json
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name","foo");
        obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
        obj.put("balance",new Integer(1000));
        obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));
        System.out.print(obj);
    }
}
```

i have downloaded the json package (json-simple-1.1.1.jar) from [google code](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/). Now i don't know how to install it in my fedora 14. I am using java version 1.6.0_20. Is there any specific version of json that i could download for this java version?

I have tried to execute it using the command

```
java -jar json-simple-1.1.1.jar
```

but i got a message showing

> "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from json-simple-1.1.1.jar"

Comment: You don't have to install it, you have to [include the jar in your classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt) when running your application

Comment: Copy the file into your lib folder inside your project or if you are using IDE(netbeans/eclipse) add it to jar libraries in your project properties

Comment: @Sandeep How do you know the OP is using an IDE?

Comment: i am not using an IDE . i am running in terminal only

Comment: @user3184228 Can you show us how are you running your application?

Comment: i would compile by specifying<code>javac json.java<code> and run by <code>java json</code>

Comment: how do i include the jar file in the class path

Answer (score 0):

You say you are running the application as

```
java json
```

Try specifying the jar in the classpath:

```
java -cp /path/to/json-simple-1.1.1.jar json
```

Where `/path/to/json-simple-1.1.1.jar` Is the path to the jar library

Comment: thank u but now i got an exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: json
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: json
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: json. Program will exit.

Comment: @user3184228 Can you update your question with the code you are trying to compile and run?

Comment: @user3184228 Are you running the command I wrote from the folder where `json.java` is?

Comment: yes both the code and the jar file are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

i just used the export statement it helped me

> [root@foss json]# export CLASSPATH=/root/Desktop/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:$CLASSPATH