# javac package bla.bla.bla does not exist

Tags: jar, javac

I am trying to compile a java file on windows that contains an import statement to classes inside another jar file.

The classes inside the jar file is compiled with java version 1.5, and the javac command is using java version 1.7.

What would be the correct syntax for the javac command to include the referenced jar file?

It does not seem to matter what I do, it just fails with a **package does not exist** exception.

Thanks!

Comment: See here [javac classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt) summary: java -cp jar1:jar2:jar3:dir1:. HelloWorld

Comment: not working: javac -cp .:myJar.jar:. Test.java
Test.java:1: error: package bla.bla.bla does not exist
import bla.bla.bla;

Comment: not working: javac -cp "lib/\*:." Test.java
Test.java:1: error: package com does not exist
import com.*;

Comment: not working: javac -cp "lib/myJar.jar:." Test.java
Test.java:1: error: package com does not exist
import com.*;