# CMD compile using jar files

Tags: java, cmd

How can I add two or more jar file in the compile step using cmd?

using one jar file:

```
javac -g -cp YOUR_JAR.jar YOUR_FILE_NAME.java
```

Any ideas how to compile two jar files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the `-classpath` flag.

```
javac -classpath your.jar:my.jar ...
```

The delimiter between jars changes according to your platform.

You can read about that by running `javac -help` or reading the [`javac` documentation online](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) and [About Setting the Class Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB).

You will notice there that the documentation says:

> Multiple path entries are separated by semicolons with no spaces
>   around the equals sign (=) in Windows and colons in Oracle Solaris.

So, all Xnix operating systems use a `:` as delimiter, whereas Windows use a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your question is about using multiple jars as the classpath when compiling java source code.

To use multiple jar/classpath files when compiling, you should separate them by your target platforms path separator, this is ';' on windows, and ':' on linux, example:

```
javac -g -cp FIRST.jar;SECOND.jar MY_FILE_NAME.java    (windows)
javac -g -cp FIRST.jar:SECOND.jar MY_FILE_NAME.java    (linux)
```

Sources: [Including jars in classpath on commandline (javac or apt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt) (java and javac have the same classpath parsing