# How to run jar from cmd with reference

Tags: java, jar

I downloaded a package in java, which I'll call `package1`, and I created a second package, which I'll call `package2`. `package2` has a reference to `package1`.

Now I need to export `package1` to a `JAR`. I exported it (and in the process created a manifest file that specified the `main` file of the package).

When running `package1` from the commandline (`java -jar package1.jar`), how do I "connect" it to `package2`? That is, when I run `java -jar package1.jar` I get errors about not finding specific classes that appear in `package2`.

Comment: You need to add package2 also into the classpath

Comment: @Arin - thanks, I'm not sure how...?

Comment: Follow these links 1>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath  2>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt

Comment: Also view this link "5 ways to add multiple JAR in to Classpath in Java" :http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html

Comment: Please add the full error you're getting, including after trying the suggestions here.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `package2.jar` to `-cp` argument to your `java` command line:

```
java -cp package2.jar -jar package1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work at least on windows:

```
java -cp "package1.jar;package2.jar" com.example.app.Main
```

where `com.example.app` is the path down the packages to your main class and `Main` is your main class.