# " org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource

Tags: java, spring

I am going to read properties from Spring.xml file and I am getting below an exception.

Can you please tell me where the mistake is.

**`Test.java`**

```
public class Test {

    private Properties driver;
    public void setDriver(Properties driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void printData(){
        Set keys = driver.keySet();
        for(Object key : keys){
            System.out.println(key+":"+driver.getProperty((String) key));
        }
    }
}
```

spring.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" 
            "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="t" class="beans.Test">
        <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />   
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**`Client.java`**

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
        Test t = (Test) ap.getBean("t");
        t.printData();
    }
}
```

Below is the exception of what I am getting...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 't' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'URL' of bean class [beans.Test]: Bean property 'URL' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at test.Client.main(Client.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'URL' of bean class [beans.Test]: Bean property 'URL' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

A ClassNotFoundException indicates that the necessary class is not  in your classpath, you need spring jdbc in your classpath, you can find id here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-jdbc%22 and you can aggregate it in your maven project like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

or gradle:

compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.2.0.RELEASE'

Comment: I am not using maven, simply added jars to run spring example. is there any other solution without this ...<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: You should download and add the necessary jars to your buildpath in your IDE or indicates in the classpath option in your java command [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt)

Comment: I have already added spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE. lets try to add spring-jdbc-4.2.0.RELEASE.

Comment: i have tried spring-jdbc-4.2.0.RELEASE but cant get success, same Exception, can you please look again  spring.xml, i think somewhere in xml having problem

Comment: Where are you running your code? simple compile and run, IDE, generated jar or application server?

Comment: I am running in Eclipse JAVA EE

Comment: I think that you are adding the Spring libraries from eclipse Library, and this does not contain spring-jdbc dependency, then you must add an external jar in your project build path.
    -Right click on the name of the project.
    -Build Path > Add External Archives
    -and select the spring-jdbc jar

or
    -Right click on the name of the project.
    -Build Path > Configure Build Path
    -Libraries and add external jar.

Comment: sir, same way I am doing and adding external jars but i think problem is not in adding jars, problem should be in spring.xml

Comment: Ok, your context loader does not work because your bean "t" definition is incorrect, check that your properties names and values, example "user" property must be "username", also "connectionCachingEnabled" does not exist and you will must add the mysql driver dependency in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using maven then add this library [commons-dbcp-jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.2.2/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar) in your classpath. This should solve your problem.