# Failed to find ij package

Tags: java, package, imagej

today, I've tried to run my ImageJ plugin My_S but ImageJ always gives off the following Warning:

```
 Plugin or class not found: "My_S"
 (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: My_S)
```

I think that it kind of skips the compiling step, because there is no My_S.class file in the plugin folder. 
This is a little weird, because it worked before (I tried it for one plugin only though).
Then I tried to compile it from the console with

```
javac My_S.java
```

which gives off the following qarning:

```
My_S.java:1: package ij does not exist
import ij.*;
^
```

So, I tried to re-install it (my system is linux mint btw) but IJ still shows off the same behavior.... : / 
Are there any suggestions on how to solve this problem? (I hope this is the right place to ask this question)

Thanks

Comment: Anything that is imported and does not belong to the Java standard library has to be added to the classpath when compiling.

Comment: Thank you and also: how do I find out where the IJ package is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ij package" (that is, all classes in `ij.*`) is found in the ij jar, e.g. `ij-1.50e.jar` distributed with your ImageJ installation.

To compile your plugin with javac, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt) about adding jars to the classpath.

However, if you are going to be developing ImageJ plugins regularly I encourage you to learn about the software development tools available, like [Maven](http://imagej.net/Introduction_into_Developing_Plugins#Getting_started_with_Maven), which will help you manage dependencies and build your compile-time classpath automatically (among other things).

You may also be interested in the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/), which reaches a more targeted community for ImageJ-specific development issues.