# How to add javax.mail package in jre file

Tags: java

I've writing a java program to send email using normal text editor (eg sublime).So, while compiling it shows javax.mail package doesnot exists and i've download javax mail package and activation but I cannot found where to save those package to run that email program...so please help me wheather to save those downloaded package and the detailed process of saving those package to work properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including jars in classpath on commandline (javac or apt)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute your java class by including the downloaded jar into class path.

Let your Java class is `HelloWorld`.
And you need classes from **TOOLS.jar** in your program.
Run your java program from command prompt using this command

```
java -cp <path>\TOOLS.jar; HelloWorld
```