# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException launching Minecraft forge server

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

That happens when I run my Minecraft forge `server.bat`

```
 A problem occurred running the Server launcher.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:43)
        at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Level
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:94)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Level
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

when i start my `server.bat`
that happens
inside my `start.bat`

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -jar forge_server.jar
PAUSE
```

Comment: Do you have enough space for your JVM ? You need to add org.apache.logging.log4j jar to your run path.

Comment: how? can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried posting/searching this problem on the Forge Forum yet? I think they might be able to give more specific help than on SO: link: http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including jars in classpath on commandline (javac or apt)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt)

Comment: you should write your minecraft version, and forge version.

Answer (score -2):

This is what you should have:

```
java -server -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=256M -jar forge_server.jar
```

Comment: `-XX:PermSize=256M` is the default. It's pointless to include it.