# Run eclipse java program from cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

I have written a java program which uses many jar files using eclipse.
However , eventually i want to run the program from command line.
The class files are in the bin folder and the .java files are in the src file.

How can i run the program from command line including all the libraries and jar files?

Thank you

Comment: In eclipse: have a look at export -> runnable jar file. More general approach: use a dependecy managment tool like maven or gradle.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt