# How to import class from jar files

Tags: java, android, import, aide

I have cloned an open source game from github using AIDE. I have the problem when im trying to compile it, i got about 2000+ errors. One of it is :

```
  unknown packages or type : "badlogic"
```

the  error code is :

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
```

at the 'badlogic' word.
When i check the classname from the libs/gdx.jar ,it seems the classname is already the same. if there anyway to solve this? thank you.

Comment: If the classes are not part of the project being compiled, you must [tell the compiler where to look them up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt).

Comment: have u added all needed jar to the classpath, or classpath of IDE?

Comment: @nikeshjoshi oh yeah, i didnt notice that i've left some class path, now its work fine 