# Import customize package shows "error: package com does not exist"

Tags: java, package

this is my file tree:

```
$ tree
.
├── Hi.java
├── com
│   └── libai688
│       ├── User.class
│       └── User.java
```

this is my Hi.java:

```
import com.libai688;

public class Hi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User p1 = new User();
    }
}
```

while I am trying to compile Hi.java

```
$javac Hi.java
Hi.java:1: error: package com does not exist
import com.libai688;
          ^
Hi.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        User p1 = new User();
        ^
  symbol:   class User
  location: class Hi
Hi.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        User p1 = new User();
                      ^
  symbol:   class User
  location: class Hi
3 errors
```

it throws a long error, I carefully check it with some other project, but I still can not find what is wrong with it.

As I know, in some other language, if you want to import a customized module it should write a relative path. But in Java, I am confused with how to import a third-party module or a customized muddle.

This is my User.java

```
package com.libai688;

public class User{
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public User(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including jars in classpath on commandline (javac or apt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Just invalid usage of the `import` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `import com.libai688;` is not good.

---

- You need to import the class you need :

  ```
  import com.libai688.User;
  ```
- Or the whole package stuff :

  ```
  import com.libai688.*;
  ```

Comment: here's an interesting post about whether or not to include a package with a wildcard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad