# Could not find or load main after adding classpath

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I am trying to run a java program on command line, but I keep getting the error message:

> Could not find or load main class AnnualExam

I tried all this and still could not find or load class

```
java -classpath "C:\jcodes\dev\ocpPrep\chapter1OCA\javaBasics" com.university.AnnualExam
```

from

> /c/jcodes/dev/ocpPrep/chapter1OCA/javaBasics

Here is the code

```
class AnnualExam {
    public static void main(String  args[]){
        System.out.print("Hello word");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including jars in classpath on commandline (javac or apt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt)

Comment: try this C:\jcodes\dev\ocpPrep\chapter1OCA\javaBasics\com\university\AnnualExam

Comment: @GauravBahadur, it is still the same thing. Am still not getting it please help

Comment: How does your AnnualExam class looks like, does it have the correct package? Does it provide a Main method?

Comment: @OluwatobiAdenekan Please edit your question to include the full source code of the `AnnualExam` class. Also write the full error message you get when you try to run the application.

Comment: I have done that. Thanks