# Java : can't find javacv pointer class

Tags: java, javacv

I have installed the Javacv jar file here : 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavacvjar.htm

After extracting the zip file I put the .jar file in the ext folder located inside the jre folder.

But whenever i try to run a code like this after importing the proper libraries

`IplImage img;`

```
  while (true) {

   //inser grabed video fram to IplImage img
   img = grabber.grab();

   //Set canvas size as per dimentions of video frame.
   canvas.setCanvasSize(grabber.getImageWidth(), grabber.getImageHeight()); 

   if (img != null) {      
     //Flip image horizontally
     cvFlip(img, img, 1);
    //Show video frame in canvas
    canvas.showImage(img);               
    }
```

i get an error like this :

error: cannot access Pointer

```
   if (img != null) {
```

class file for com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer not found

Comment: I'm not showing the rest of the code since that's not the problem

Comment: Are u using an IDE? You might need to add it to the classpath

Comment: I'm using sublime text 3. It works with other jar files like the asprise OCR jar file

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: I created a tool that makes me compile and run the code in the windows 10 command prompt that goes like this { "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","&&","start","cmd","/k","java", "$file_base_name"], "path":"C\\programmi\\jdk1.8.0_181\\bin", "shell": true }

Comment: Look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt

Comment: Unfortunately after making a new sublime-build (and adding the class path leading to the jars and the main methods) it still give me the same error