# Java Servlets: Tomcat server find MongoDB classes and packages

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, servlets, server

I'm trying to connect a MongoDB database to Tomcat. I downloaded the three 3.10.1 Java Driver jar files, `mongodb-driver-3.10.1-javadoc.jar`, `mongodb-driver-3.10.1-sources.jar`, and `mongodb-driver-3.10.1.jar`. I added them to `WEB-INF\lib`. I also added a MongoDB resource in `META-INF\context.xml`, and a resource reference in `WEB-INF\web.xml`. Still, Tomcat is saying that the package com.mongodb does not exist. Does anyone have a fix for this?

My context.xml file:

```
<Context reloadable="true">

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="mongodb/MyMongoClient"
          auth="Container"
          type="com.mongodb.MongoClient"
          closeMethod="close"
          factory="com.mongodb.client.jndi.MongoClientFactory"
          singleton="true"
          connectionString="mongodb://localhost:80"/>

</Context>
```

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Test</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestCheck</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>TestCheck</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestCheck</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/testCheck</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>
            mongodb/MyMongoClient
        </res-ref-name>
        <res-type>
            com.mongodb.MongoClient
        </res-type>
        <res-auth>
            Container
        </res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

My Test.java file:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import java.io.IOException;


import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;

@WebServer("/test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {


        //Connect
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:80"));


        DB database = mongoClient.getDB("testDB");
        DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("testCollection");

        DBObject testDoc = new BasicDBObject("_id", "This is a test");

        collection.insert(testDoc);

        //close
        mongoClient.close();

    }

}
```

And finally, the output from the command prompt after trying to compile:

```
Test.java:11: error: package com.mongodb does not exist
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
                  ^
Test.java:12: error: package com.mongodb does not exist
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
                  ^
Test.java:14: error: package com.mongodb does not exist
import com.mongodb.DB;
                  ^
Test.java:15: error: package com.mongodb does not exist
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
                  ^
Test.java:16: error: package com.mongodb does not exist
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
                  ^
Test.java:17: error: package com.mongodb does not exist
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
                  ^
Test.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
@WebServer("/test")
 ^
  symbol: class WebServer
Test.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mo
ngodb://localhost:80"));
                ^
  symbol:   class MongoClient
  location: class Test
Test.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mo
ngodb://localhost:80"));
                                              ^
  symbol:   class MongoClient
  location: class Test
Test.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mo
ngodb://localhost:80"));
                                                              ^
  symbol:   class MongoClientURI
  location: class Test
Test.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
                DB database = mongoClient.getDB("testDB");
                ^
  symbol:   class DB
  location: class Test
Test.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
                DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("testCollection
");
                ^
  symbol:   class DBCollection
  location: class Test
Test.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
                DBObject testDoc = new BasicDBObject("_id", "Hello!");
                ^
  symbol:   class DBObject
  location: class Test
Test.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
                DBObject testDoc = new BasicDBObject("_id", "Hello!");
                                       ^
  symbol:   class BasicDBObject
  location: class Test
14 errors
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are the jar files also in the build path of your project?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Tomcat, it's compiler. To add the MongoDB libraries to Tomcat is needed to be able to **run** the (web)app, but in order to **compile** it you have to add them to the compiler's classpath. If you use the `javac` directly, see the `-cp` switch (or have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43666499)), if you use some build system (like Maven), look into its documentation how to add a compile dependency.