# Importing jar file to use like a library but having an error

Tags: java, class, jar, compilation, classnotfoundexception

First of all thank you for reading my question.
I have a .jar file and .java file which I should compile

They are "fractals.jar" and "FractalsTest.java"

So basically "fractals.jar" contains .class files with packages to run a simple program that displays fractals on a java program, and the directory looks like this.

```
fractals -- FractalExplorer
          | FracalGenerator
          | JImageDisplay
          + generator -- Mandelbrot
                      -- BurningShip
                      -- Tricorn
```

So, The top three classes are under directory(folder) and package called "fractals"
the the three fractal patterns under directory(folder_ and package named "fractals.generator"
FractalGenerator utilizes the three fractal pattern classes by importing them, and FractalExplorer class
is the class that contains the main function.
I have succeeded in compiling the six classes and compressed them as "fractals.jar" file with manifest including "Main-Class: fractals.FractalExplorer". Eventually, the "fractals.jar" file runs perfectly fine.
But my goal here is to make another java file that utilizes the "fractals.jar" file like a library to run the same thing!!!
So here is the code of "FractalsTest.java"

```
import fractals.*;

public class FractalsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FractalExplorer fracExp = new FractalExplorer(800);
        fracExp.createAndShowGUI();
        fracExp.drawFractal();
    }
}
```

I tried compiling it by entering on the cmd like this:

```
>javac -classpath fractals.jar FractalsTest.java
```

(assuming they both are on desktop)

It compiles perfectly fine, and "FractalsTest.class" is created.

And now all I need to do is entering

> java -classpath fractals.jar FractalsTest

BUT!!!! The console screen shows that
`"Could not find or load main class FractalsTest"` with `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FractalsTest"`

Please help!!!What mistakes have I done?????

Answer (score 0):

I guess `java -classpath fractals.jar FractalsTest` searches for `FractalsTest.class` inside `fractals.jar`. Simple `java FractalsTest` should do the trick.

Edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2096298) states that the current directory must be manually added to the classpath. So add `:.` at the end of your classpath to include the current directory.

Comment: C:\Users\H.G\Desktop>java FractalsTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fractals/FractalExplorer
        at FractalsTest.main(FractalsTest.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fractals.FractalExplorer
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more

Comment: Sorry, I just had to learn something about the classpath myself. Thanks for the stacktrace, this lead me to the (hopefully correct) solution.