# Selenium for Intellij "Package does not exist"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I continue to get the following error when trying to compile a simple java application using selenium in IntelliJ in Windows 10:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                          ^
.\SeleniumTest.java:2: error: package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
                                 ^
.\SeleniumTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        ^
  symbol:   class WebDriver
  location: class SeleniumTest
.\SeleniumTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                               ^
  symbol:   class ChromeDriver
  location: class SeleniumTest
4 errors
```

I have tried everything suggested by gpt and various tutorials. This includes creating a lib folder in my project directory, right clicking and selecting "Add as Library".

I have also gone to

> Project Structure>Modules>Dependencies>+>Jars or Directories
> And added all the jar files in the selenium-java-4.12.0 and selenium-java-4.12.0/lib directories.

The only thing I haven't attempted is using a build manager like Maven or Gradle, simply because I've been told that as a beginner it is better to start by managing your packages manually.

I just can't figure out why IntelliJ is not finding the jar files. I created JAVA_HOME and added java to my environment variables. I have rebuilt the project and started from scratch probably a dozen times and I'm still getting the same error.

I'm using JDK 17.0.8 and I have downloaded the most recent stable release of Selenium for Java 4.12.0 (August 31, 2023)

I am coming from python and not an experienced Java programmer at all. I feel incredibly incompetent especially considering how quickly I'm able to get a Selenium build running in python.

Here's some screen shots of my project:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I have discovered that there is no issue if I simply run the file from intelliJ. However the issue only occurs when I attempt to compile the java file through the IntelliJ terminal. I don't know why this is or how to resolve it. I assume it is related to the selenium jars not being in the PATH. But I have attempted to add them with no luck.
[image]

Comment: Python is a higher level language than Java, whatever you know about Python probably won't help you with Java. As for the error, well it's a classpath issue. If you've configured things randomly, it probably won't work (randomness doesn't work in software development, you need to understand what you're doing). Try running on the commandline with `javac / java` instead and set the classpath explicitly.

Comment: Do you see WebDriver class in the selenium-java-4.12.0 lib? Please provide screenshots from `File | Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies` and `File | Project Structure | Libraries` and clarify from where did you download this JAR?

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I'll have to get the screenshots tomorrow. As for the jar files they were downloaded directly from the official selenium site: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/download/selenium-4.12.0/selenium-java-4.12.0.zip

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I see the WebDriver java file under selenium-api-4.12.0.jar>org.openqa.selenium

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I've added the screenshots you have requested as well.

Comment: If you're building JAR manually from the command line you have to add dependencies to the classpath manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2096298/12844632

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, to build a JAR file you can configure an artifact under `File | Project Structure | Artifacts` and include Selenium dependency there. Then use `Build | Build Artifacts...` action from the IDE main menu. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I really appreciate it. Adding the classpath to my javac command resolved the issue: "java -classpath "C:\Users\Dr.Tautology\Selenium\jars\*" TestSelenium.java"